# Difference between now and given date in Persian calendar

Tags: javascript, date, datetime-format

Here is a code to get the difference between two times.

```js
// input your custom Date below
var date = new Date('2020-06-12 22:00:00');
var dif = (date.getTime() / 1000) - ((new Date().getTime())/1000);
var end = Math.max(0, dif);
console.log(end);
```

I want to be able to change the Gregorian date to Persian (Solar Hijri) like this:

```
var date = new Date('1399-03-23 22:00:00');
```

I have used `.toLocaleDateString('fa-IR');` but it causes errors...

Comment: Dates in the format 1399-03-23 22:00:00 are not supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari returns an invalid date.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [this library](https://github.com/farhadi/JalaliJSCalendar/blob/master/jalali.js) for conversion:

```js
let input = '1399-03-22 12:34'

let date = new Date(input)
let [y, m, d] = JalaliDate.jalaliToGregorian(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate())
date.setFullYear(y)
date.setMonth(m)
date.setDate(d)

console.log(date)
```

```html
<script>
  /*
   * JalaliJSCalendar - Jalali Extension for Date Object 
   * Copyright (c) 2008 Ali Farhadi (http://farhadi.ir/)
   * Released under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
   * See the GPL for details (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html).
   * 
   * Based on code from http://farsiweb.info
   */

  JalaliDate = {
    g_days_in_month: [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
    j_days_in_month: [31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29]
  };

  JalaliDate.jalaliToGregorian = function(j_y, j_m, j_d) {
    j_y = parseInt(j_y);
    j_m = parseInt(j_m);
    j_d = parseInt(j_d);
    var jy = j_y - 979;
    var jm = j_m - 1;
    var jd = j_d - 1;

    var j_day_no = 365 * jy + parseInt(jy / 33) * 8 + parseInt((jy % 33 + 3) / 4);
    for (var i = 0; i < jm; ++i) j_day_no += JalaliDate.j_days_in_month[i];

    j_day_no += jd;

    var g_day_no = j_day_no + 79;

    var gy = 1600 + 400 * parseInt(g_day_no / 146097); /* 146097 = 365*400 + 400/4 - 400/100 + 400/400 */
    g_day_no = g_day_no % 146097;

    var leap = true;
    if (g_day_no >= 36525) /* 36525 = 365*100 + 100/4 */ {
      g_day_no--;
      gy += 100 * parseInt(g_day_no / 36524); /* 36524 = 365*100 + 100/4 - 100/100 */
      g_day_no = g_day_no % 36524;

      if (g_day_no >= 365)
        g_day_no++;
      else
        leap = false;
    }

    gy += 4 * parseInt(g_day_no / 1461); /* 1461 = 365*4 + 4/4 */
    g_day_no %= 1461;

    if (g_day_no >= 366) {
      leap = false;

      g_day_no--;
      gy += parseInt(g_day_no / 365);
      g_day_no = g_day_no % 365;
    }

    for (var i = 0; g_day_no >= JalaliDate.g_days_in_month[i] + (i == 1 && leap); i++)
      g_day_no -= JalaliDate.g_days_in_month[i] + (i == 1 && leap);
    var gm = i + 1;
    var gd = g_day_no + 1;

    return [gy, gm, gd];
  }

  JalaliDate.checkDate = function(j_y, j_m, j_d) {
    return !(j_y < 0 || j_y > 32767 || j_m < 1 || j_m > 12 || j_d < 1 || j_d >
      (JalaliDate.j_days_in_month[j_m - 1] + (j_m == 12 && !((j_y - 979) % 33 % 4))));
  }

  JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali = function(g_y, g_m, g_d) {
    g_y = parseInt(g_y);
    g_m = parseInt(g_m);
    g_d = parseInt(g_d);
    var gy = g_y - 1600;
    var gm = g_m - 1;
    var gd = g_d - 1;

    var g_day_no = 365 * gy + parseInt((gy + 3) / 4) - parseInt((gy + 99) / 100) + parseInt((gy + 399) / 400);

    for (var i = 0; i < gm; ++i)
      g_day_no += JalaliDate.g_days_in_month[i];
    if (gm > 1 && ((gy % 4 == 0 && gy % 100 != 0) || (gy % 400 == 0)))
      /* leap and after Feb */
      ++g_day_no;
    g_day_no += gd;

    var j_day_no = g_day_no - 79;

    var j_np = parseInt(j_day_no / 12053);
    j_day_no %= 12053;

    var jy = 979 + 33 * j_np + 4 * parseInt(j_day_no / 1461);

    j_day_no %= 1461;

    if (j_day_no >= 366) {
      jy += parseInt((j_day_no - 1) / 365);
      j_day_no = (j_day_no - 1) % 365;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 11 && j_day_no >= JalaliDate.j_days_in_month[i]; ++i) {
      j_day_no -= JalaliDate.j_days_in_month[i];
    }
    var jm = i + 1;
    var jd = j_day_no + 1;


    return [jy, jm, jd];
  }

  Date.prototype.setJalaliFullYear = function(y, m, d) {
    var gd = this.getDate();
    var gm = this.getMonth();
    var gy = this.getFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    if (y < 100) y += 1300;
    j[0] = y;
    if (m != undefined) {
      if (m > 11) {
        j[0] += Math.floor(m / 12);
        m = m % 12;
      }
      j[1] = m + 1;
    }
    if (d != undefined) j[2] = d;
    var g = JalaliDate.jalaliToGregorian(j[0], j[1], j[2]);
    return this.setFullYear(g[0], g[1] - 1, g[2]);
  }

  Date.prototype.setJalaliMonth = function(m, d) {
    var gd = this.getDate();
    var gm = this.getMonth();
    var gy = this.getFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    if (m > 11) {
      j[0] += Math.floor(m / 12);
      m = m % 12;
    }
    j[1] = m + 1;
    if (d != undefined) j[2] = d;
    var g = JalaliDate.jalaliToGregorian(j[0], j[1], j[2]);
    return this.setFullYear(g[0], g[1] - 1, g[2]);
  }

  Date.prototype.setJalaliDate = function(d) {
    var gd = this.getDate();
    var gm = this.getMonth();
    var gy = this.getFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    j[2] = d;
    var g = JalaliDate.jalaliToGregorian(j[0], j[1], j[2]);
    return this.setFullYear(g[0], g[1] - 1, g[2]);
  }

  Date.prototype.getJalaliFullYear = function() {
    var gd = this.getDate();
    var gm = this.getMonth();
    var gy = this.getFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    return j[0];
  }

  Date.prototype.getJalaliMonth = function() {
    var gd = this.getDate();
    var gm = this.getMonth();
    var gy = this.getFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    return j[1] - 1;
  }

  Date.prototype.getJalaliDate = function() {
    var gd = this.getDate();
    var gm = this.getMonth();
    var gy = this.getFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    return j[2];
  }

  Date.prototype.getJalaliDay = function() {
    var day = this.getDay();
    day = (day + 1) % 7;
    return day;
  }


  /**
   * Jalali UTC functions 
   */

  Date.prototype.setJalaliUTCFullYear = function(y, m, d) {
    var gd = this.getUTCDate();
    var gm = this.getUTCMonth();
    var gy = this.getUTCFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    if (y < 100) y += 1300;
    j[0] = y;
    if (m != undefined) {
      if (m > 11) {
        j[0] += Math.floor(m / 12);
        m = m % 12;
      }
      j[1] = m + 1;
    }
    if (d != undefined) j[2] = d;
    var g = JalaliDate.jalaliToGregorian(j[0], j[1], j[2]);
    return this.setUTCFullYear(g[0], g[1] - 1, g[2]);
  }

  Date.prototype.setJalaliUTCMonth = function(m, d) {
    var gd = this.getUTCDate();
    var gm = this.getUTCMonth();
    var gy = this.getUTCFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    if (m > 11) {
      j[0] += Math.floor(m / 12);
      m = m % 12;
    }
    j[1] = m + 1;
    if (d != undefined) j[2] = d;
    var g = JalaliDate.jalaliToGregorian(j[0], j[1], j[2]);
    return this.setUTCFullYear(g[0], g[1] - 1, g[2]);
  }

  Date.prototype.setJalaliUTCDate = function(d) {
    var gd = this.getUTCDate();
    var gm = this.getUTCMonth();
    var gy = this.getUTCFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    j[2] = d;
    var g = JalaliDate.jalaliToGregorian(j[0], j[1], j[2]);
    return this.setUTCFullYear(g[0], g[1] - 1, g[2]);
  }

  Date.prototype.getJalaliUTCFullYear = function() {
    var gd = this.getUTCDate();
    var gm = this.getUTCMonth();
    var gy = this.getUTCFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    return j[0];
  }

  Date.prototype.getJalaliUTCMonth = function() {
    var gd = this.getUTCDate();
    var gm = this.getUTCMonth();
    var gy = this.getUTCFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    return j[1] - 1;
  }

  Date.prototype.getJalaliUTCDate = function() {
    var gd = this.getUTCDate();
    var gm = this.getUTCMonth();
    var gy = this.getUTCFullYear();
    var j = JalaliDate.gregorianToJalali(gy, gm + 1, gd);
    return j[2];
  }

  Date.prototype.getJalaliUTCDay = function() {
    var day = this.getUTCDay();
    day = (day + 1) % 7;
    return day;
  }
</script>
```